# My custom cursor doesnt work if I use the LiveServer port, but works using the html directory

Tags: html, css

```css
html {
  cursor: url('C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/website/pinkCursor.cur'), auto;
}
```

Im using this to specify the cursor directory, it works if I use the same directory (**file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/website/website.html**) on the browser, but if I try to use the LiveServer plugin, the cursor doesnt work, it uses the default cursor from windows.

**This is using the directory on browser:**

[image: This is using the directory on browser]

**This is using the LiveServer plugin:**

[image: This is using the LiveServer plugin]

**Error message:**

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use relative paths to your assets.

Try:

```css
html {
  cursor: url('pinkCursor.cur'), auto;
}
```

This means the **.cur** file is in the same folder as the loaded page.